# Aggregate data and plot in a bar plot in R

Tags: r, statistics

i have a data set with parameter_variations and a score. This score has four scales: like, anth, comf and ueq.

Comment: Hi Shalomi, The `bargraph.CI` function accepts raw data, not aggregated data. So try the following: `bargraph.CI(parameter_variants, response=score, group=scale, data=dat, main="likeability")`.

Comment: Thank you @Edward that works and it is cool but I will need a legend for that. Do you know how?

Comment: But I till want to create a plot for every scale not in one plot four scales. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: LIKE THAT:  like2 <- aggregate (score ~ scale + parameter_variants + velocity, data = dat, mean)
bargraph.CI(parameter_variants, score(scale=="like"), data=like2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bargraph.CI` function accepts raw data, not aggregated data. So try the following:

```
bargraph.CI(parameter_variants, response=score, group=scale, data=dat,
            main="likeability", legend=TRUE)
```

This should give you one "two-way" plot. If you don't like the look of it, there are many arguments that make superficial adjustments. Check the help page for details.

To obtain separate plots for each of the four scales, I think you can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
    dat %>%
    filter(scale=="like") %>%  # change the value here.
    bargraph.CI(parameter_variants, response=score, data=., main="likeability")
```

---

Base R solution:

```
with(subset(dat, subset=scale=="like"),
        bargraph.CI(parameter_variants, response=score, main="likeability")
)
```

Comment: I dont get the last code. It does not work. Error in filter(scale == "like") : 
  argument "filter" is missing, with no default

Comment: You have to load the dplyr library. And possibly force its use: `dplyr::filter(...)`

Comment: I did load dplyr

Comment: Do you know any other solutioN?

Comment: Did you try: `dplyr::filter(scale=="like")` ?

Comment: I shown you another solution using base R (no need to load dplyr library).